# Using NHibernate with lookup tables

Tags: database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lookup

If you have a set of tables in the database that strictly consist of a string description and an ID, what is the best way to load these via NHibernate?

So suppose I have a Sandwich class, and a sandwich has a meat, a cheese, and a vegetable, where those three things are lookup tables in the DB.  It seems to be the most conformant to NHibernate philosophy to have

```
public class Meat { string name; int id; }
public class Cheese { string name; int id; }
public class Vegetable { string name; int id; }
public class Sandwich { Meat meat; Cheese cheese; Vegetable vegetable; }
```

But with a few dozen tables like this in the database, classes seem to proliferate quickly.  Suppose I set it up like this:

```
public class NameAndID { string name; int id; }
public class Sandwich { NameAndID meat; NameAndID cheese; NameAndID vegetable; }
```

Is this feasible?  How would it be implemented in Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need another column to determine the type. You could use an enum for that. Then all your lookups need to include that restriction....

```
CreateCriteria<NameAndID>.Add(Restrictions.Eq("ntype", E.Meat)
```

However, I'd prefer separate tables so you can have better foreign keys. Otherwise there is nothing in database constraints to stop you from making a sandwich that is simply 3 pieces of cheese.

Comment: I was actually thinking about keeping the separate tables and having them all map to NameAndID.  Is that possible?

Comment: Kind of...just add empty class definitions that inherit from NameAndID. You'd still need to map each one though.